# Use SwiftyJSON in Singleton

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to use [SwiftyJSON](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/swiftyjson-how-to-handle-json-in-swift/111) to store some JSON data but keep running into compiler errors.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class CurrentUser {
    private struct SubSruct {
        static var currentUser: JSON? = nil
    }

    private init(){

    }

    class var currentUser: JSON? {
        get { return SubSruct.currentUser }
        set { SubSruct.currentUser = newValue }
    }
}
```

Specifically, the following compiler error happens: `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`.

If I change the type from `JSON` to anything else the compiler error goes away (I've tried both `AnyObject` and `NSDictionary`).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: A segmentation fault means that you've found a compiler bug. Congratulations!

Comment: I think that class vars are not supported yet in mainstream Xcode releases. Try moving the struct outside of the class (but in the same file), and avoid class vars; these are the two least usual things in your code that I can spot, and they are the most likely to cause issues.